# MC/DC - How to manage a decision not 100% coverage

Tags: code-coverage, test-coverage, mc-dc

considering the decision "**(A && B) || (!A && C)**", this leads to a lack of MC/DC coverage, for istance it's impossible to test **F#F#**.

1. What does it mean to not reach 100% of MC/DC? Is it just a quality
   issue?
2. Is it acceptable to not have 100% of MC/DC?
3. How to manage the decision to reach 100% of MC/CD?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but can you explain the "F#F#" notation?

Comment: the notation "F#F#" represents a possible combination of "condition" values to test the "decision". In particular, "F#F#" says there are 4 "condition" and the test is about value False for the first and third conditions and  "don't care" for the second and fourth conditions (they can be True o False, it's no relevant).

Comment: Thanks, but there are only three variables here.  What are the four conditions?  If they are "A", "B", "!A", "C", then of course you can't test F#F#, because you can't have A false and !A false.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions, let's first take a look at some of the components of an MC/DC criteria:

More details here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage#Definitions

- Condition - a condition should be an atomic boolean expression.
- Decision - a boolean expression composed of zero or more boolean operators and a decision without a boolean operator (AND and OR) is only a condition.

Given your example expression (A && B) || (!A && C), we can break it down into three conditions "A", "B" and "C". Take note that A and !A are both boolean expressions, but one of them is not atomic.

We can then create a Truth Table:

[image: Truth Table]

Highlighted in yellow are the "possible" MC/DC evaluations we can come up with.

After identifying, we then select which of the identified items are the "real" MC/DC evaluations which will give us 100% coverage. How do we identify the "real" evaluations?

[image: Truth Table - Identified]

We identify pairings (TRUE and FALSE) of each conditions **and** the decisions with every row possible. In the image above, the rows with orange highlights are the "real" MC/DC evaluation that will give us 100% branch coverage and 100% condition coverage.

Remember that it should output at least **n+1** tests.

---

1. If your MC/DC coverage is not 100%, it can mean that there is something wrong with the way your conditions are being created. Why? Take this simple example **(A && !A)**, when condition "A" is true, then the decision is false; when condition "A" is false, then the decision is still false. This classic example, in programming, can lead to unreachable codes. Unreachable codes are useless and won't ever be executed.
2. The purpose of MC/DC is to identify flaws in your decision expressions. This will be a case-to-case basis as there are critical software that require certain level of perfection, like in aviation where MC/DC is most commonly used to prevent failures. In most software development activities, where conditions are common, 80% - 90% is the acceptable range for coverage.
3. Re-evaluate your conditions. Take time to understand the logic and flow of the application. One of the activities we did before was to generate a Control Flow Graph (CFG) paired with Truth Tables to identify correctness of logic. A (CFG) is a graphical representation of a certain boolean expression. It is similar to a flow chart, where a condition node can either be true or false and passing all of the condition nodes will lead to a certain decision.

Hope this helps!